# Javascript wrong variable type

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeof

Hello I'm preparing little guessing word game. 
Somehow the type of my variable get changed from string to obj type what causes an **Uncaught TypeError.**
Here is a fragment of code:

```
let passwordArray = ["Java Script Developer", "FrontEnd"];
let sample = passwordArray[Math.floor((Math.random() * 
    passwordArray.length))];
let password = sample.toUpperCase();
let new_password = "";

for(let x =0; x<password.length;x++){
    if(password[x]===" "){new_password += " "}
    else{new_password += "-"}
}
$("#password span").text(new_password);
```

This part works correclty problem appears when I want to repalce a letter

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, replacement){
return this.substr(0,index) + replacement + this.substr(index + replacement.length)
};

function check(num) {
let test = false;
let temp = $(event.target).val();
if(password.indexOf(temp)>-1){test=true; /*alert(test +"/"+temp+"/"+password)*/}
$("#"+num).attr("disabled", true);
if(test === true) {
    $("#"+num).removeClass("letter").addClass("hitletter");
    let indeksy =[];
    for(let i =0; i<password.length;i++ ){
        if(password.charAt(i) === temp){indeksy.push(i)}
    }
    for(let x=0; x<indeksy.length;x++) {
        let indx = indeksy[x];
        new_password = new_password.replaceAt(indx, temp);
    }
    $("#password").html(new_password);
}};
```

My HTML basically is just:

```
<nav>
    <input type="button" value="o mnie" id="me">
    <input type="button" value="kalkulator" id="cal">
    <input type="button" value="Wisielec" id="wis">
    <input type="button" value="Memory" id="mem">
</nav>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Rest is dynamically added in JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#wis").click(function () {
    $("#content").empty().append("" +
        "<div id='container'>\n" +
        "<div id='password'><span>Sample text</span></span></div>\n" +
        "<div id='counter'>Counter: <span id='result'></span></div>\n" +
        "<div id='gibbet' class='image'></div>\n" +
        "<div id='alphabet'></div>\n" +
        "<div id='new'>\n" +
        "<input type='text' id='new_password'/>\n" +
        "<button id='add' onclick='newPass()'>Submit</button>\n" +
        "</div>\n" +
        "</div>"
    );
    start();
});
});

function start(){
    let new_password = "";
    $("#contetn").empty();
    let letters = "";
    for(let i=0; i<32; i++){
        letters += "<input class='letter' type='button' value='"+litery[i]+"' onclick='check("+i+")' id='"+i+"'/>"
}
    $("#alphabet").html(letters);
    $("#result").text(mistakeCounter);

    for(let x =0; x<password.length;x++){
        if(password[x]===" "){new_password += " "}
        else{new_password += "-"}
    }
    $("#password span").text(new_password);
}
```

The problem is that variable new_password is somehow changing from type string to type object when i want to use function replaceAt()

Comment: can you post the HTML as well

Comment: What is the message of the type error, and in which line does it happen?

Comment: Your replaceAt function works fine. If I call it on a string e.g. `var str = 'mohit'; str.replaceAt(1, 'x'); returns 'mxhit';` so it's returning a string.

Comment: Bergi Erro message is:
"Uncaught TypeError: new_password.replaceAt is not a function"





                                         Mohit Bhardwaj
Yes it works when I use random string I mean when I create var and then use replaceAt. But when I am creating a var with function start() and then I'm trying to use function check(num) with replaceAt inside then is it not working and throwing me an error as above.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code, with the new String.prototype.replaceAt this error can happen on 2 situations:

when the variable that uses replaceAt is not a string, example:

```
null.replaceAt(someIndex,'someText');
{}.replaceAt(someIndex,'someText');
[].replaceAt(someIndex,'someText');
```

the other situation is when you pass null or undefined as replacement:

```
"".replaceAt(someIndex,undefined);
"".replaceAt(someIndex,null);
```

just add some verification code and should be working good

Comment: When I check the typeof new_password after using start() function the type is String. But when I want to use replaceAt in check(num) function for the same var(new_password) then it returns me error "Uncaught TypeError".